# iMac 27" (mid 2011) self assigning IP

Tags: network, wifi, ethernet

I have a problem with my iMac, that it keeps self assigning IP on **WiFi and Ethernet**.
So far I've tried to

- Renew DHCP lease
- Typing the IP/submask/router IP/DNS manually (says I'm connected to the internet, but can't ping anything)
- Deleting the files shown below from /library/preferences/SystemConfiguration
- Disabling firewall
- Running Wireless Diagnostics (no results)
- Trying 3rd party USB Ethernet adapter
- Trying my mobile's hotspot

```
com.apple.airport.preferences.plist
com.apple.network.identification.plist
NetworkInterfaces.plist
```

It's worth mentioning, that I can see corresponding MAC-address on my LAN, but can't ping from or to  the machine. All of the other machines in my network do work correctly. I've yet to reinstall the OS as I do not wish to do that if possible.

> Edit: I can ping TO the machine

> Edit 2: I can ping `1.1.1.1` from the recovery tools terminal. Will further investigate what's the problem with the OS

> Edit 3: So I painstakingly backed up the computer and did a fresh install of macOS 10.13.6 and everything seems to be working correctly. I frankly don't have any idea what the problem could've been as I read the log files for hours and didn't find a solution. I tried to disable multiple things with no success.

Comment: Have you looked at  the Network preferences GUI?  Select the interface, then Advanced, then TCP/IP.

Comment: As I wrote earlier `Typing the IP/submask/router IP/DNS manually (says I'm connected to the internet, but can't ping anything)`, yes. Did not work.

Comment: Cool.  Wasn’t clear _where_ you typed it.